# ARKit Moving Horizontal Plane Visualization

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm able to create a horizontal plane the moment I detect a flat surface, but I am wondering if there is a way to display it while moving around similarly to the feature point debugging option?

Essentially, I want the plane to move with you, not add on to the plane.

Comment: Do you mean update the visualisation if the planes increases its extent?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have interpreted your question correctly, you are essentially asking how can I update the visualisation of a detected plane as it increases in size etc.

There are a number of different ways that this can be achieved, but in this instance I will provide an example using a subclass of `SCNNode` which will update as the plane increases.

```
    class PlaneNode: SCNNode {

    let DEFAULT_IMAGE: String = "defaultGrid"
    let NAME: String = "PlaneNode"
    var planeGeometry: SCNPlane
    var planeAnchor: ARPlaneAnchor

    var widthInfo: String!
    var heightInfo: String!
    var alignmentInfo: String!

    //---------------
    //MARK: LifeCycle
    //---------------

    /// Inititialization
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - anchor: ARPlaneAnchor
    ///   - node: SCNNode
    ///   - node: Bool
    init(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor, node: SCNNode, image: Bool, identifier: Int, opacity: CGFloat = 0.25){

        //1. Create The SCNPlaneGeometry
        self.planeAnchor = anchor
        self.planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(anchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(anchor.extent.z))
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)

        super.init()

        //2. If The Image Bool Is True We Use The Default Image From The Assets Bundle
        let planeMaterial = SCNMaterial()

        if image{

            planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: DEFAULT_IMAGE)

        }else{

            planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
        }

        //3. Set The Geometries Contents
        self.planeGeometry.materials = [planeMaterial]

        //4. Set The Position Of The PlaneNode
        planeNode.simdPosition = float3(self.planeAnchor.center.x, 0, self.planeAnchor.center.z)

        //5. Rotate It On It's XAxis
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

        //6. Set The Opacity Of The Node
        planeNode.opacity = opacity

        //7. Add The PlaneNode
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        //8. Set The Nodes ID
        node.name = "\(NAME) \(identifier)"

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }


    /// Updates The Size Of The Plane As & When The ARPlaneAnchor Has Been Updated
    ///
    /// - Parameter anchor: ARPlaneAnchor
    func update(_ anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {

        self.planeAnchor = anchor

        self.planeGeometry.width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
        self.planeGeometry.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)

        self.position = SCNVector3Make(anchor.center.x, 0.01, anchor.center.z)

    }

  }
```

Having created our subclass we then need to use it within our ViewController.

You will normally get more than one `ARPlaneAnchor` and would probably store these in a dictionary, however in this example we just assume there will be one.

As such we will create a variable which will reference our PlaneNode:

```
var planeNode:PlaneNode?
```

Then in the `ARSCNViewDelegate` we will create our PlaneNode like so:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

//1. Get The Current ARPlaneAnchor
guard let anchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

//2. Create The PlaneNode
if planeNode == nil{
    planeNode = PlaneNode(anchor: anchor, node: node, image: true, identifier: 0, opacity: 1)
    node.addChildNode(planeNode!)
    planeNode?.name = String("Detected Plane")
  }

}
```

Then all you need to do is track the updating of the PlaneNode so that the visualization keeps updating e.g:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    guard let anchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor, let existingPlane = planeNode else { return }
    existingPlane.update(anchor)
}
```